# file hplip-3.13.9

Tags: hplip

Install two week ago : Ubuntu 13.04 with Gnome and Cairo-Dock
Had message to update hplip 3.13.3 to hplip 3.13.9

Install new hplip from HP site using automatic installer, followed instructions.
The automatic installer put on the desktop hplip3.13.9 run and at the end of installation a second file was on the desktop. This contains 46,5 Mo

Can I send to the garbage the run file and put the other file at the right place without affecting hplip and the printer?

Comment: we are not sure of what exactly you are asking ? what do you need exactly ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Those files in your **Desktop** where only temporary, you can remove them without problems. Everything is installed in your system root.

Comment: Is it the person who ask the question or the moderator that put the question is resolve